# Is good practice implement tests to validate tests automation it self?

Tags: unity-game-engine, testing, automation

I want to know input about the next subject:

Is it usual and/or good practice to implement tests that will be testing automation tests, i.e., I have a test automation project over an API project and want to know if I should create unity tests to apply to my test automation code, or this is overloading work and unnecessary? In advanced I want to thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

I see no issue.  You can have unit tests that run when your code changes or as part of a CI/CD pipeline.  However, Unity adds an additional layer via the [Unity Test Framework (UTF)](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.test-framework@1.1/manual/index.html) where you can tests automatically in the Editor or Play mode.  You can also invoke unit tests manually by creating a [menu extension](https://forum.unity.com/threads/running-unit-tests-on-c-scripts.693136/).

Depending on what you define as an *"API project"* and assuming this API project has nothing to do with Unity, you might want to consider exporting your API code (if it isn't already) into a stand-alone .NET Framework 4.x project where you can pre-compile the code into a DLL that you can copy into Unity as a [Managed Plugin](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UsingDLL.html).  [Unity also supports .NET Standard 2.1 (.NET Core 3.0) or lower](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/dotnetProfileSupport.html).

The nature of the external, Unity-independent project allows you to use whatever frameworks for performing *integration testing* with your API.

Once all tests complete you can copy your DLL into Unity as a plug-in.  Here Unity allows you to create additional tests via UTF.  Because these tests are in Unity you can call both plain-old .NET as well as Unity APIs.

### See also

- Blackbird Interactive, *"Unite 2013 - Nurturing Large Projects: How We Structured Hardware: Shipbreakers"*, https://youtu.be/q9aeNtKKXeo?t=1773